# apex5.0, disable button when another button is clicked

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

How to disable a button in oracle apex if another button is clicked.
I have buttons in a classic report.
btn1: Update
btn2: Delete
btn3: Save

I would like when one of the button is clicked, the others buttons should be disabled.
Pls advise how to do that

Comment: Are your buttons submitting the page or just performing a dynamic action? If they submit the page, you need to think of a way for the new page to know what state the buttons should be in.

Answer (score 0):

What happens when one of the buttons is clicked?  Knowing this could provide a better way of doing what you want, such as with a server-side condition.

Not knowing this, you could do it with dynamic actions - on button click of particular button, disable / hide the other buttons (set multiple true actions).  You would also want to specify when to reset them.

Comment: when the button is clicked, it updates the flag in the oracle table.  when one button is clicked then others should be disabled.. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Ive tried to do it via DA but its not working.. it's doing the update only and not the disable / hide option... however if i remove the update its doing the hide/disable... Any idea?

Comment: Does the flag have 3 separate values for each button?  If so you could just have server side condition to only show button when flag is null or = whatever the buttons value is.

Re. the DA I'm not entirely sure what you mean, can you explain in a bit more detail?